# How to Close Chrome Custom Tab with Device Back Button ignoring Browsing History in the Tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, history

I open an url with chrome custom tabs and navigate within the tab. Now I want to close the custom tab and go back to the original app, but the device back button closes only after returning back all the histories in the app. I want to close the custom tab with the device back button ignoring all histories in the tab. Is this functionally possible?

```
String url = eacharticle.get("url");
String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.chrome";
android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.Builder().setShowTitle(true).build();
customTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
customTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
java.util.List<android.content.pm.ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(customTabsIntent.intent, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (android.content.pm.ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
if(PACKAGE_NAME.equals(packageName))
customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(PACKAGE_NAME); // force use chrome if installed
}
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
```